# google sign-in api trying to access unexisting DOM element

Tags: google-signin

I am implementing simple google sign-in button as described in [google sign-in docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#specify_your_apps_client_id), auth works, but in the console I got the error:

```
cb=gapi.loaded_0:247 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of nullG_ 
@ cb=gapi.loaded_0:247(anonymous function) 
@ cb=gapi.loaded_0:251(anonymous function) 
@ cb=gapi.loaded_0:145c.port1.onmessage 
@ cb=gapi.loaded_0:72
```

after inspecting in the minified google code, it looks like it tries to access unexisting DOM elements:

```
document.getElementById("not_signed_in"+a.El) 
//it prints: "not_signed_invrnlb3wwqpsh"
```

the auth works, but the error is affecting me when I try to use this same code inside an angular.js app. this is the simple html code to reproduce the error:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_APP_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
}
</script>
<p>please sign in</p>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is caused by async behavior by angular (or any other frameworks could behave similarly). If that is the case, I'd recommend to render the button manually rather than using `.g-signin2`.

Using `gapi.signin2.render()` is the easiest option to control button rendering timing.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#customizing_the_automatically_rendered_sign-in_button_recommended

But you could also use `.attachClickHandler()` to inject sign-in functionality to your custom button.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#building_a_button_with_a_custom_graphic